# What is Python Decimal(32) equivalent in Swift?

Tags: python, swift

I need to translate a decompression algorithm from Python to Swift and I'm having trouble with number formats. What is the equivalent of `Decimal` in Swift and what does the parentheses notate, particularly `num -= Decimal(32)`?

```
for char in compressedData:
    num = Decimal(safeCharacters.index(char))
    if num < 32:
        point.append(num)
        pointsArray.append(point)
        point = []
    else:
        num -= Decimal(32)
        point.append(num)
```

Comment: I believe Decimal(32) just create a Decimal object with a value of '32'. You can take a look at the [decimal documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Comment: So decimal would be equivalent to `Double` in Swift? i.e. `Double(32)`

Comment: No.  Decimal is for doing exact arithmetic with decimal numbers.  Double is binary floating-point.  I don't know if Swift has an equivalent to Decimal but if it does, it isn't Double.  For example, you can express 3-tenths exactly as a Decimal, but not as a Double.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of Python's `Decimal` is Objective-C's `NSDecimalNumber` which can be used from Swift as well. As of today, there is no native Swift type for doing exact decimal arithmetic. See the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/index.html) for further info.

As mentioned in the comments, `Decimal(32)` creates the number `32` in decimal representation.